# Ka for reaction from tables

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

For the reaction below:

NH4+ + H2O -> NH3 + H30+

I have the following values from a table to use:

[image]
[image]

And in the solution manual they tell me to use the Ka for this reaction. Why is this? Why do we use the Ka for NH3 when it is NH4 acting as an acid?

Comment: As you pointed out $\ce{NH3}$ is a base and $\ce{NH4+}$ is an acid. There is really no point in listing both in a table on separate lines since $$K_a \times K_b = K_w$$

Comment: You are strictly right. Ka refers not to the acidity constant of $\ce{NH3}$ but to that of its conjugate acid, $\ce{NH4+}$

Comment: @BuckThorn states the matter closer to the 'truth." The column labeled "pKa" should really be labeled  "pKa of conjugate acid." As chemists we understand the implicit relationship.